# Facial and image recognition doesn't work with NSFW pics

Tags: google-photos

Quote from Wikipedia:

> The Photos service analyzes and organizes images into groups and can
>   identify features such as beaches, skylines, or "snowstorms in
>   Toronto". From the application's search window, users are shown
>   potential searches for groups of photos in three major categories:
>   People, Places, and Things. The service analyzes photos for similar
>   faces and groups them together in the People category. It can also
>   group faces as they age. The Places category uses geotagging data
>   but can also determine locations in older pictures by analyzing for
>   major landmarks (e.g., photos containing the Eiffel Tower). The
>   Things category processes photos for their subject matter: birthdays,
>   buildings, cats, concerts, food, graduations, posters, screenshots,
>   etc. Users can manually remove categorization errors.

I uploaded about 1000 NSFW pics (80% from internet and 20% self made). I don't see any of those smart features described.

Is there some NSFW censorship?

There is no grouping/tags and here are some example searches

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I suspect it's because you're words are a little more meta. Have you tried searching for the body parts in question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very likely that the Google Photos team block "NSFW" related keywords in order to prevent content policy violations.

From https://www.google.com/intl/en-US/+/policy/content.html (emphasis mine)

> ## User Content and Conduct Policy
>
> Google’s social and sharing products and services enable people from
> diverse backgrounds to start conversations, share experiences,
> collaborate on projects, and form new communities. Our policies play
> an important role in maintaining a positive experience for our users
> on the products listed below (collectively referred to as the
> “Services”). Please follow these policies as you:
>
> - use Google+, including Google+ comments on other products such as Blogger
> - participate in publicly shared Hangouts or Hangouts on Air
> - send Hangouts invitations
> - share content by link through **Google Photos**
> - use Spaces.

...

> #### 9. Sexually Explicit Material
>
> **Do not distribute** sexually explicit or pornographic material. Do not
> drive traffic to commercial pornography sites.
>
> We do allow naturalistic and documentary depictions of nudity (such as
> an image of a breastfeeding infant), as well as depictions of nudity
> that serve a clear educational, scientific, or artistic purpose.
>
> Note that your Google+ profile photo cannot include mature or
> offensive content. For example, do not use a photo that is a close-up
> of a person’s buttocks or cleavage.